# How to diagnose or lower "waiting" time for web content?

Tags: php, linux, apache, lag

I keep seeing inconsistent performance on a server of mine, and I'm finding it hard to diagnose/fix the problem. For the most part, pages load quickly, but 10-20% of the time they load very slowly. In Chrome's network tab shows "waiting" time as 99% of the lag. I've even tested loading a blank PHP page that has no output and I still see the wait time get large on 10-20% of page views.

I've tried timing the PHP script and it is consistently low on all page views, including the ones that have long wait times. For example, I could load the blank page and it will load in 150ms, and then I load it again and it loads in 8500ms, but both times the PHP script executed in <.5ms.

Any ideas on what else could be causing this (I've tested on multiple computers/networks and am getting reports from users from around the world)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Connection issues/packet loss**

Could it be a high packet loss on your connection?  TCP connections sometimes reach timeouts where there is packet loss, whereby it misses a connection initially, but then (in worst case) manages to connect after some seconds worth of retrying.

Of course, you'd notice issues not just viewing your site, but any site on that connection.

**Contention on the server**

Is it a shared server, and could other clients on the same server be using an excessive amount of IO or CPU, or active Apache processes, at times?

You would debug this with the `top` command (to see general CPU usage or load queue) or the `ps -AH v` command (to see the number of active Apache processes and an overview of the other processes running too).

Comment: It isn't my internet connection/computer. I've tested on multiple computers/networks and am getting reports from users from around the world. Also, it isn't a shared server, and there is almost no load on the server.

Comment: Do you use Apache?  How many processes/what's your MaxClients?  How much RAM?  Did you look at the process list and at the output from top?

Comment: Okay, turns out WHM reset MaxClients to 150 for some reason. Thanks for reminding me to check that, set it to 512 and everything is flying!

Comment: You must have a huge amount of RAM and fairly high traffic then :)  Perhaps in future questions you could include details such as amount of server RAM, type of app/traffic etc.

Answer (score 0):

With internet servers there are alot of areas that can cause issues with load times. I have had similar results with one website I manage. With the internet, it composes of multiple areas. The software/hardware on your computer, your router, your ISP gateway, the path it takes to get to your hosting, the gateway of your hosting, and the software/hardware on your server. All these can cause bottlenecks depending on current load. The most common reason of waiting time is the lookup or stored routing table. This is your computers arp and network cache and can be cleared to see if it corrects (this has helped in some cases). Instead of trying to get the fastest route it uses old paths which may now have high loads.

The second reason is that your server may be low on resources. This can be more true if you are on shared hosting. If you have a dedicated server, I would check your resource usage when it seems to be slow. There could be a process that is hogging the resources at certain times, example is a cron job.

Without checking these there is no way to know what the issue is. The only thing I can say is to check everything you can and run tracerouts/pings to check the server times and the path you are using.

Comment: I've checked everything I can think of, which is why I posted here as a last resort. It isn't my computer/network because I've tested multiple computers & networks, and have gotten reports of the same thing from other users. This is on a dedicated server. It still does it even if no cron jobs are running, and overall resource usage is very low.